# Borshdeserializer in PHP

Tags: solana

is there an equivalent PHP code for borshdeserializer? I'm asking because i have base64 data that i want to parse in PHP, same as how borshdeserializer is doing .

Sample data that i have:

```
["account"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["data"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          string(908) "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"
          [1]=>
          string(6) "base64"
        }
        ["executable"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["lamports"]=>
        int(5616720)
        ["owner"]=>
        string(43) "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
        ["rentEpoch"]=>
        int(262)
      }
      ["pubkey"]=>
      string(44) "CvupBt6vJ5m81ZBBdTULtPzDR2M6Hv97wVdbVQWNa5bn"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like it, unless there's an unofficial implementation out there: https://github.com/near/borsh#implementations

On the other hand, it could be an excellent open-source project if you implement it!